# react to multiple actions in redux toolkit's createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm refactoring my reducers to use the redux-toolkit's `createSlice`.
Now I have a very event-based reducer and sometimes a similar state update for different actions is required
.
With the original `switch/case` statement this was no issue:

```
        case ActionTypes.CREATION_CANCELLED:
        case ActionTypes.NEW_MARKER_INFOWINDOW_CLOSED:
        case ActionTypes.MARKER_SELECTED:
            return {...state, isCreating: false};
```

Is this kind of behaviour possible with a `createSlice` function?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supported out of the box, but you can always create a helper function that takes a `state` and returns the same state but with `{isCreating: false}` and use that function in multiple places.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using [the `extraReducers` "builder callback" notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation).  With this notation you create a reducer by adding cases to a `builder` object.  The first argument of the [`builder.addMatcher`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#builderaddmatcher) function determines which action types match this case.

If your actions share a common string format, you can use string-based matchers like `action.type.endsWith('/rejected')` to handle all `rejected` actions the same way.

Otherwise you can define your own custom matcher function that takes an `action` and returns a `boolean` of whether or not it's a match.

Since we want to match multiple action types, we can create a helper for that.

```
// helper function to match any actions in a provided list
// actions can be `string` types or redux-toolkit action creators
const isAnyOf = (...matchers: Array<string | { type: string }>) => 
  ( action: AnyAction ) =>
    matchers.some((matcher) =>
      typeof matcher === "string"
        ? matcher === action.type
        : matcher.type === action.type
    );
```

We can use this with your existing `string` constants:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "some name",
  initialState: {
    someProp: [],
    isCreating: false
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    return builder.addMatcher(
      isAnyOf(
        ActionTypes.CREATION_CANCELLED,
        ActionTypes.NEW_MARKER_INFOWINDOW_CLOSED,
        ActionTypes.MARKER_SELECTED
      ),
      (state, action) => {
        state.isCreating = false;
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Or with Redux Toolkit action creators:

```
const creationCancelled = createAction("CREATION_CANCELLED");
const newMarkerInfoWindowClosed = createAction("NEW_MARKER_INFOWINDOW_CLOSED");
const markerSelected = createAction("MARKER_SELECTED");

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "some name",
  initialState: {
    someProp: [],
    isCreating: false
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    return builder.addMatcher(
      isAnyOf(creationCancelled, newMarkerInfoWindowClosed, markerSelected),
      (state, action) => {
        state.isCreating = false;
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: `isAnyOf` is now actually part of redux-toolkit https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isanyof
Yet, it's not supporting strings as you introduced here :)

Comment: Interesting how this used to be very clean code with readability and now it is not. I thought the Redux toolkit was supposed to make using redux more simple.